# Embedding individual label into plotly express histogram

Tags: plotly, histogram, plotly-python, plotly-express

I'd like to embedded individual label(s) into each bar of the plotly express histogram.

As an example:

```py
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
    
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['label1', 'label2','label3', 'label4', 'label1'],
                   'val1':[1,2,1,2,1]})

px.histogram(df, x='val1', nbins=3)
```

[image]

Is it possible to have `['label1', 'label3']`, `['label2', 'label4']` appear in the 1st and 2nd columns of the histogram plot, respectively?

Answer (score 1):

- work out data in **pandas** as well
- add additional information onto figure as annotations

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
    
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['label1', 'label2','label3', 'label4', 'label1'],
                   'val1':[1,2,1,2,1]})

fig = px.histogram(df, x='val1', nbins=3)

# work out bins in pandas...
df2 = (
    df.groupby(pd.cut(df["val1"], bins=3))
    .agg(
        count=("name", "size"),
        labels=("name", lambda s: ",".join(s.drop_duplicates().tolist())),
    )
    .assign(
        l=lambda d: [i.left for i in d.index.values],
        r=lambda d: [i.right for i in d.index.values],
        x=lambda d: [(i.left+i.right)/2 for i in d.index.values],
        count=lambda d: d["count"].astype(float)
    )
).fillna("")

# add text to histogram
for r in df2.iterrows():
    fig.add_annotation(text=r[1]["labels"], x=(r[1]["l"]+r[1]["r"])/2, y=r[1]["count"]+.2, showarrow=False)

fig
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for your solution Rob. Much appreciated! I was however simplified the problem since my dataset has many more classes in **Val1** and also many long description of individual **labels** in each class. So being more precisely, I was looking to see if the top 10 labels for example would appear interactively when hovering the mouse to each bar.

Comment: pretty simple - just 5 labels: `labels=("name", lambda s: ",".join(s.drop_duplicates().tolist()[0:5]))`

Comment: if you want to build as hover,  I would go for changing to a **px.bar** rather than histogram.   You have everything you need in **df2** to generate a simple bar figure